# StartApp -> No such module 'StartApp'

Tags: ios, swift, startapp

Using [StartApp](http://www.startapp.com/) in a Swift app I have this issue (Xcode 7.3.1). On the line:

```
import StartApp
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
No such module 'StartApp'
```

I have my StartApp.bundle and StartApp.framework set, and the Framework Search Paths are also set.

I already used StartApp in an Objectiv-C app before and I did have this problem.

Any idea to solve this issue would be welcome.

Comment: That's odd. They are usually good if you contact their support

Comment: @Michel - were you able to find any solution to this problem?